# What is the effect of a neodymium magnet on a smartphone's touch screen?

Tags: capacitance, magnet

What are the possible effects of multiple neodymium magnets in relatively close proximity to the capacitive touch screens most smartphones use nowadays?

As the screens themselves are LEDs the image should not be affected (unlike the old CRTs), but I'm not sure about the touch components.

Comment: You should try it and f there is something weird going on, please give us some info.

Comment: I'm currently having those magnets on my phone (about 2 years old) but can't figure out if they're affecting the touchscreen or if my on-and-off touchscreen problems are just a result of other issues.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially none. The magnetic field isn't strong enough to disrupt the electric field used for sensing.

However, many phones contain a magnetometer for measuring compass direction, which definitely will be affected by a magnet. I've seen claims of magnetic case clasps permanently affecting the calibration of the magnetometer, but I don't know how true these are

Comment: I've seen the same claims, but those are relatively uninteresting (GPS alone will give you direction anyway, while driving). Is there any theoretical possible effect?