# Fingerprint scanner fails when magnetized

Tags: identification, electromagnetic

Question: Why does a fingerprint scanner fail to work when magnetized?

I took the fingerprint scanner out of an old LG V30 phone because it is a scanner and a push button and is pretty. I added it to my project and it worked fine. Then, when I packaged it all together, the fingerprint scanner is right next to the wireless charging pad, which creates a rather weak, but persistant magnetic field. I found that if the charging pad is powered for a few seconds, the fingerprint scanner fails to work. After turning off the magnet, the fingerprint scanner takes a good ten minutes to start working again.

If I take it all out of the enclosure and keep the fingerprint scanner well away from the charging pad, it works without trouble.

So, I tested magnets. If I put a magnet near the fingerprint scanner, it quickly stops working. If I take the magnet away, it continues to fail for a long time. Degauzing fixes it quickly. This tells me that the scanner is becoming magnetized and then failing to work.

I searched LG support forums and I found that many people reported that their LG V30's fingerprint scanner failed to work if they used a wireless charger for their phone. Note: On the LG V30, the scanner is centered on the back of the phone, which would be in direct contact with a wireless charger.

More experiments. I tested this in the back yard in 30 degree temperatures. It fails quickly and takes many minutes to fix after the magnet is moved away. I tested this inside in 70 degree temperatures. It still fails quickly, but fixes itself faster. Again, this tells me that it is some form of magnetizing.

So, to the question at the beginning. Why does the fingerprint scanner get magnetized and fail? What exactly is happening? How do I keep it from happening - other than keeping all magnets very far away from the scanner?

Note: I can't find a category for identity scanning devices, so I think identification circuits is as close as I can get. If that is wrong, please recategorize this.

Comment: Could be not the scanner itself, but the surrounding electronics.

Comment: *Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.* - best addressed to the people who designed it or manufacture it.

Comment: I disagree, @Andy. This is a "what's the principle of operation" question and I, for one, would be interested in an answer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. This is a very good image of the scanner with related chip. It could be the chip, but I can't separate the two. The ribbon cable is too short and I don't want to mess with trying to extend it. https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/enUAAOSw-I9czF-~/s-l1600.jpg

Comment: Might be related a bit: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/295271/what-is-the-effect-of-a-neodymium-magnet-on-a-smartphones-touch-screen The FP sensor is capacitive as well as far as I can tell, so I would not expect it to be influenced by static magnetic field. Probably some indirect effect.

Comment: Could try magnetically-shielding the CPU or sensor, and try again.

Answer (score 2):

Long after sending this question to multiple people at LG, I received a very brief response: This is a known issue. The metal ring around the capacitor array was replaced with a plastic ring.

I interpret that as the metal ring, being a metal loop, when placed in a magnetic field should produce electric current. Many people do that as a science experiment either making electricity with a magnet or making a magnet with electricity. By replacing the metal loop with a plastic loop, the problem goes away. The old project was finished with a different sensor and sent off, so that fix is no longer applicable for me.